# Django not able to load a simple static page with static files

Tags: python, html, django, static

It is a simple static html file with only one image as a static file in the html. I have followed all the steps provided in the Django documentation, and the `collectstatic` command runs without any error.

The project folder structure is as follows;

[image]

settings.py file;

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')

DEBUG = True
```

home.html - File where the image is not loading;

```
{%load static%}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  >
<head>
<title>home.html</title>

<h1>This is a test file</h1>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="{% static 'images/test.png' %}">
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

I have tried the following;

1. Restart server,
2. rerun the `collectstatic` command

Nothing worked out, What could be the issue? Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace STATICFILES_DIR with STATICFILES_DIRS in settings.py

Comment: This worked! I did not suspect 'STATICFILES_DIR' typo error as 'collectstatic' was working without any error. Thank you for identifying the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')` whereas it looks like you've already collected your files to `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`, which is a more typical location. You should change `STATIC_ROOT` to point back to the static folder so that Django knows where to serve those files from:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

You can see this in the [static files deployment guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#deployment)

Answer (score 0):

try this in your settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
def get_success_url(self, request, user):
    return (get_success_url)
```

and add this from your urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
           ......
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns +=static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

STATICFILES_DIR is the main error here.
Replace it with STATICFILES_DIRS
This should solve it.